# Gtk.Revealer SLIDE_RIGHT / SLIDE_LEFT issue?

Tags: gtk, vala

I'm having issues with the Gtk.RevealerTransitionType SLIDE_RIGHT / SLIDE_LEFT types. Only wit those types I see no animation. The child simply disappears or appears, in some case after a delay. Example:
[image]

The other animations, like SLIDE_DOWN work fine:
[image]

I've created a simple example project:
https://github.com/peteruithoven/Revealer-transitions

It looks like when I change the orientation of the Box that this Revealer is in from vertical to horizontal, the issue moves to the SLIDE_UP / SLIDE_DOWN transitions:
[image]

**Update**: It looks like Gtk.Revealer takes orientation into account in some way:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkrevealer.c#L310-337
I also found an related open issue:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1020